# Can we hide the code from user - from admin too?

Tags: magento2, javascript, extensions

We are in a process of website development *(Website is not Launched yet)* and I found that website development company developers are hiding code from admin panel and when we are asking them to tell us where is chat script code they said that it's all over the place and they will extra quote us for remove tracking codes - [image]

Do we need to add chat script all over the place???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chat script code should be in one place and not "all over the place", unless someone who did not know decided to add the code in several places. From the looks of it they're trying to extra quote you. If it's a script it should be in a certain location. If its an extension then yes code might be disbursed throughout different folders on your server.